# Ruby: Handle arbitrary method names

Tags: ruby

I remember watching a ruby screencast from Dave Thomas about using metaprogramming to create method names that do not need to adhere to identifier syntax requirements. Typically, an identifier must not contain spaces. And he showed how to create methods with spaces. But I don't remember how it's done.

I have arbitrary field names for a class that `include`s Mongoid::Document. This works fine, where _field can be a string like 'Hello World':

```
MyClass.class_eval <<-EOS
  field :'#{ _field }', type: #{_type}
EOS
```

I want to override the setter. So I tried this:

```
MyClass.class_eval <<-EOS
  field :'#{ _field }', type: #{_type}
  def #{ _field }=(val)
    self['#{ _field }'] = [self.send('#{ _field }')[0], val]
  end
EOS
```

Unfortunately, if the _field is a string like 'Hello World', I will get an error:

```
SyntaxError: (eval):2: formal argument cannot be a constant
           def Hello World=(val)
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Just because the property is called `"Hello World"` inside MongoDB doesn't mean that you have to (or even should) use that name in Ruby. Part of an ORM/ODM's job is to deal with he impedance mismatch between the database and the code that is using the O[RD]M, renaming database properties/fields to match Ruby attribute conventions would certainly be a part of that.

Comment: You are aware, that Mongoid supports [dynamic fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.0.0/mongoid-documents/#dynamic-fields) out of the box, aren't you?

Comment: @muistooshort you are right. My decision was to use the :as option Mongoid provides: field :'Hello World', type: Array,  as: :hello_world

Comment: Nice. I thought Mongoid had aliasing built in. That should make everything work smoother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`define_method` lets you do this:

```
define_method(:"hello world") { puts 'hello world' }
send :"hello world"
```

But you have to call it with `send` since the method name in normal invocation syntax is not allowed either.

---

You can do this from a class definition as well.

```
class MyClass
  def name
    @name
  end

  define_method :"set name" do |new_name|
    @name = new_name
  end
end

instance = MyClass.new
instance.send :"set name", 'Bob'
instance.name #=> Bob
```

---

Lastly, I feel obliged to say this is probably a terrible idea. I'm not sure *exactly* what you're after here, but there is probably a better way. `:can != :should`.

Comment: I am working with Rails and Mongoid, I don't think Rails will ever explicitly invoke it without using send.

Comment: A method name with spaces in it is pretty nuts, but it's also possible as you demonstrate here.

Comment: @Donato because you typically using syntactically valid method names, since the method names are what you type in your code to to do stuff. If you are generating methods like this you probably want a method that accepts keys as an argument. I bet Mongoid has an interface under the hood that looks like `instance.set('hello world', 'new value')` (or something). And that's probably what you want to override.